# How can I make a smoothie that will last 6 months and still be drinkable afterward if unopened?

Tags: drinks

How can I make a smoothie that will last 6 months and still be drinkable afterward if kept unopened?

The drink must:

- Taste and have the texture of a smoothie
- Be drinkable after 6 months (still in good flavor without rotting)
- Be stable at room temperature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repackaging shelf-stable products](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108275/repackaging-shelf-stable-products)

Comment: Welcome to SA!  For folks to answer this question, you'll need to define what "the taste and texture of a smootie" is to you.